# Controlar Exception de datos duplicados Mysql en C#

Tags: c#, mysql, excepciones

!Buenas!

No encuentro nada respecto a controlar la excepción de valores duplicados en una tabla de MySql en C#.

Tengo este comando, por ejemplo:

```
        cmd.CommandText = $"insert into tarea(id_agenda,dia,mes,hora,descripcion,lugar) values ('{id_agenda}','{dia}','{mes}','{hora}','{descripcion}','{lugar}')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Y si introduzco valores donde la PK vaya a estar duplicada sale de la aplicación y salta la `Exception`. ¿Como puedo controlarla? No encuentro nada al respecto.

Se que hay que utilizar el `try catch`, pero no se cual es el tipo de `exception` que debo colocar en el `catch`

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Tienes la posibilidad de usar sp? si es asi usa uno y de lado del sp lo puedes dejar devuelves un mensaje si existe o no, no trates de insertarlo hazlo desde el sp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendaria que no generes tu mismo la `PK`sino que defienas como `AUTO_INCREMENT`

[3.6.9 Using AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

[SQL AUTO INCREMENT Field](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)

entonces ya no tienes que asignarle uno desde codigo y no tendras este exception

Ademas deberias usar parametros en el codigo, es una mala practica concatener los valores en un string

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("<connection string>"))  
{  
    conn.Open();  

    string query = @"insert into tarea(dia,mes,hora,descripcion,lugar) 
                      values (?dia, ?mes, ?hora, ?descripcion, ?lugar)";  
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?dia", dia);  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?mes", mes);  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?hora", hora); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?descripcion", descripcion); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?lugar", lugar); 

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a capturar una Excepción del tipo `MySqlException`, y luego comprueba el código de error para clave duplicada (duplicate key = 1062).

```
try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
catch (MySqlException ex)
{
    switch (ex.Number)
    {
        case 1062:
              // Aquí gestiona la Excepción..
            break;
    }
}
```

Aquí https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-error-reference.html puedes consultar los códigos de error para MySql.